# JSON htmlentities javascript

Tags: javascript, json, string, special-characters

I am using an XMLHttpRequest to POST a JSON string to PHP. The JSON object is created in JavaScript and using the JSON2.js from json.org to create an JSON string representing the object.

`JSON.stringify(object);`

Whenever the object contains a string which has a special character in it, e.g. é, JavaScript does not give any error but PHP receives an empty array

`[]`

Is there a JavaScript function which produces the exact same resutls as the PHP function

`htmlentities()`

The data is send via POST, so the following functions

```
escape()
encodeURI()
encodeURIComponent()
```

are a bit overkill.

Thanks!

Comment: a library like JQuery will perform this encoding for you

Comment: @Andy: jQuery doesn't do anything that isn't already natively available - it uses `encodeURIComponent()`.

Comment: @Andy E of course not, but why reinvent the wheel when AJAX libs abound?

Comment: If you're creating JSON you don't want to use an equivalant to htmlentities() as that will encode the results for injection in to HTML, not Javascript

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Even when sending stuff via POST, you still need to correctly urlencode.  If the ampersand character is in the JSON body, this would be treated as a parameter/value pair separator and your JSON would no longer be valid.

`escape()` is deprecated so use `encodeURIComponent()`.  It shouldn't be overkill as this is one of the intended purposes of the function.